# Change WiFi config on headless Ubuntu server Pi zero 2 via SD card?

Tags: networking, server, wireless, raspberrypi

I have a Raspberry pi zero 2 running ubuntu server with a WiFi connection.

I want to take the pi somewhere else and hook onto the WiFi in a new location. I will not know the SSID or the password until I am there. I will have my laptop with me but with no screen, keyboard mouse or ethernet connection for the Pi. Tethering through the laptop is not an option either.

Can I alter files on the SD card to update to the new SSID and password so that the Pi will automatically connect?

If so, which files?

Comment: Please, take a look at this answer. [wifi setup](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98598/how-to-setup-the-raspberry-pi-3-onboard-wifi-for-ubuntu-server-18-04-with-netpla)

Answer (score 0):

Answering to a one year old question but others may have the same question.

1. before you go, while connected at home:

- `sudo cloud-init clean --logs`

2. before you go, mount the card in your desktop

- edit /boot/network-config

```
ethernets:
    eth0:
      optional: true
      dhcp4: true
wifis:  
    wlan0:  
      dhcp4: true  
      optional: true
```

or for a new WiFi (I like to use my iPhone hotspot - that way I know the SSID and the password)

```
ethernets:
  eth0:
    optional: true
    dhcp4: true
wifis:  
  wlan0:  
    dhcp4: true  
    optional: true   
    access-points:  
      "your_SSID":  
        password: "your_netpswd"
```

3. Before you go, reboot the system twice

- first time copies the new network-config to /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
- second time actually uses the /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
- if using your iPhone Hotspot, and you can log into the system with ether connection:

  - have the hotspot active when you boot
  - log in from ethernet, run iwconfig to see what the IP address is (it will be the same next time)

4. When you get there

- The Wifi you configured will work (e.g. iPhone hotspot)
- or if you need to set the SSID/password,

  - edit /boot/network-config
  - yank power when green light is off to reboot two- three times

Answer (score -1):

The network configuration files are in /etc/netplan. Change them as you wish :)